# Unknown error in google app script formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, switch-statement

Im trying to create a custom formula using Google App Script for a spreadsheet that given two different variables returns one numeric value.
Eg. 
a = true and b = "something" return 50
Here is the code;

```
function VALOR_KM(vehiculo, cliente) {
  var especial = (vehiculo == 'especial') ? true : false;
  var valor = 0;
  function costo(c) { valor = c };
  switch (cliente) {
    case 'asegurado':
      if (especial) costo(80)
      else costo(55);
      break;
    case 'particular':
      if (especial) costo(90)
      else costo(66);
      break;
    case 'AA':
      costo(3);
      break;
    case 'audi':
      costo(4);
      break;
    default: 
      costo(0);
      break;
  } 
  return valor;
};
```

But when i try to use it in a spreadsheet it gives me the #ERROR! "error analyzing formula" code. And I cant tell why its not working, because if i run the script like JavaScript it works.

Comment: The function costo() does not return anything. I also believe that function isn't really necessary. Check the code I posted and see if that works?

Comment: Hey @Frippie, what error do you get? If you hover over the cell that displays the `#ERROR!` message, you should see a description of it. What does it say? Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 the error i get is "error analizying formula"

Comment: @Frippie: the code worked fine when I tested. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: @Frippie: added an example screenshot to my post. Mind you that the use of comma's or semi-colons in a formula depends on your locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the formula being correct, it is not being called properly - which is what causes the `error analizying formula` error message.

As explained [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4271054?hl=en):

> The function separator for each Sheet is dependent on the the country chosen from  File> Spreadsheet setting "Locale"  - For example if you choose United States then function separator is comma but if you choose Germany then it will be a semicolon. What I have notice that each time you change the Country functions separator are automatically changed.

So essentially you just have to use the appropriate argument separator for your locale (which may be either `;` or `,`).

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
function VALOR_KM(vehiculo, cliente) {
 var valor;
 switch (cliente) {
  case 'asegurado':
  valor = (vehiculo === 'especial') ? 80 : 55;
  break;
  case 'particular':
  valor = (vehiculo === 'especial') ? 90 : 66;
  break;
  case 'AA':
  valor = 3;
  break;
  case 'audi':
  valor = 4;
  break;
  default: 
  valor = 0;
  break;
  } 
  return valor;
};
```

[image: Example]